# How to represent derivatives using integrals of functions in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)$ is a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$, we have

$\frac{f^n(z)}{n!}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^{n+1}}d\zeta$.

The question is: what is the corresponding formula for analytic function in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: In short, there really isnt, although I’m sure there are others on this site that will illustrate some special cases. This is what makes complex analysis beautiful, the much stronger connection between integration and differentiation than in real analysis.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Real_versus_complex_analytic_functions

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing you get are harmonic functions; i.e. a function $u: \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} $ with $\Delta u=0$, where $\Delta$ denotes the Laplacian. They statisfy the mean-value property, which is:
$$
u(x)= \frac{1}{|B_r(x)|}\int_{B_r(x)} u(y)dy= \frac{1}{|\partial B_r(x)|}\int_{\partial B_r(x)} u(y)dS
$$
For $n=2$ (dimension), since $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$, this translates to:
$$
u(x)=\frac{1}{2r\pi}\int_{\gamma} u(x)dS
$$
where you choose the curve $\gamma=\partial B_r(x)$. Plugging in $r=1$ makes it even more remniscent. For those harmonic functions, a lot of theorems from complex analysis apply as well, e.g. Liouvilles theorem or the maximum principle.